# Flex-wrap - Invalid Property Value

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to do simple things with flexbox and somehow I've gotten the "Invalid Property Value" message when I type "Flex-wrap: wrap". I cannot see what I'm doing wrong here and I've been stuck with this for some days, could anyone point out the mistake? I've tried removing things and starting over but somehow I cannot make the content to wrap.  I'm new with this, so any and all tips are welcome!

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <Title> Produkter </Title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>

<body>

<h1 class="center-text"> Placeholder! </h1>

  <section class="sec-home">
    

    <div class="home-text"> <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p></div>
  

        
     <div class="home-pic-div"> 
    <img class="home-pic1" src="Assets/brownie-548591_1920.jpg" alt="brownie">
     </div>

</section>
</body>
</html>







/*** Index ***/


.sec-home { 

display: flex;
padding: 15px 20px;
flex-wrap: flex;


 }


.home-pic1 {

width: auto;
height: 250px;

}


.home-pic-div {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-basis: 30%;
   margin: auto;

}


.home-text {

flex: 1 1 auto;
padding: 10px 15px;
 flex-basis: 30%;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
.sec-home {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and not

```
.sec-home {
   display: flex;
   padding: 15px 20px;
   flex-wrap: flex;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok now it is been mark as invalid since your value :flex is not right, flex-wrap acepts the following values:

```
flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Default value */
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;

/* Global values */
flex-wrap: inherit;
flex-wrap: initial;
flex-wrap: unset;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't exist

```
flex-wrap: nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse;
```